# While zoomed in on a plot in RStudio, how do I view the next plot?

Tags: plot, rstudio, zooming

Before I'm zoomed in, this is achievable with the left/right arrows on the GUI or by keyboard shortcuts. However, once I'm zoomed in to a plot, I seem to be stuck on my zoomed in plot of choice. Is there any way to view the next plot after that from within the zoom in window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I came close to this was by:

- Ctrl+Shift+6 (Windows, Linux, Mac) to enlarge plots view
- Then circle through plots with Ctrl+Alt+F11 and Ctrl+Alt+F12 (Windows, Linux) or Fn+Cmd+Option+F11 and Fn+Cmd+Option+F12 (Mac)

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F11 is a very bad keyboard shortcut for Linux. It is RStudio's default, but pressing that will put you in a new tty. I recently changed it to ctrl+left is RStudio's settings.